# Assistance with numpy savetext function

Tags: python, numpy

I am very new with python and am struggling to figure out how to output my data to a file.

The following section of my script works great, however I would like to be able to output the printed data to a text file.

```
x = np.linspace(141, 144.5, 500)
print x
y = np.linspace(-38.53, -38.53, 500)
z = np.linspace(0, 0, 500)

gz = tesseroid.gz(x,y,z,model)
print gz
```

As an addendum to that; when it prints in my terminal it prints the data as follows...

(x)

```
1 2 3 4
5 ... 500
```

(gz)

```
1 2 3 4
5 ... 500
```

...however I would love it to output the data in a single column like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
...
8
```

It would be even better if they could both be in the same file...

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
...
500 500
```

...however this is not necessary, as I could easily manually manipulate them from there.

Many thanks in advance, and apologies if it is a very simple question; it is just something that I haven't been able to figure out with my limited experience.

Edit: Please note that it does not necessarily have to use the numpy savetext function. If there is an easier way to perform this task then I am perfectly willing to use it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you title says, you can use `np.savetxt()` to save in one column:

```
np.savetxt('x.txt', x.ravel())
np.savetxt('gz.txt', gz.ravel())
```

or to save in two columns:

```
np.savetxt('x_gz.txt', np.vstack((x.ravel(), gz.ravel())).T)
```